# How to get rid of the "loaded" text in html5 audio tag in Safari

Tags: css, html, audio

I need a pure html5 audio tag with only a play/pause button.

Thanks to these links:
https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/mediaControls.css

I've been able to figure out most of the (surprisingly undocumented) -webkit-* pseudoelements that make up the audio controls, and assign them a "display:none" rule in CSS so that they don't show up. I've been able to make the volume control, mute control, seekbar, etc all disappear, but **Safari in MacOS** still shows a **text** next to the play button which I says "**Loaded**" (or something like that: it says "Carico" in Italian).

Is it possible to prevent that text from being displayed? I guess it belongs to some other pseudoelement but I can't find a way to figure out which one (the element inspector doesn't help).

I've tried to apply a "font-size: 0" to the containing pseudoelements but it doesn't work.

My stylesheet:

```
audio {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 0;
}
audio * {
    font-size: 0;
}

/* https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334 */
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    max-width: none; /*or inherit*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0 !important;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure * {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}
audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    /*background: black;*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel * {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container, audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display, audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display, audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container, audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider, audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button, audio::-webkit-media-controls-closed-captions-container, audio::-webkit-media-controls-closed-captions-track-list {
    display: none;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    padding: 0;
    /*width: 30px;
    height: 30px;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to hide the audio element using display:none, and then add in some nice css play, pause, stop icons, using either images or maybe css fonts downloaded from [fontello](http://fontello.com), and on click just fire off the play, pause stop methods.

Comment: That's not an option for me because I need it to be accessible for screen readers and the like, for blind people. I need to style a real <audio> element with controls.

Comment: I've already used audio.js to render a fully customizable player, but the dom structure it generates is not friendly to accessibility tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By browsing the source code of WebKit (or what seems to be it https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Source/WebCore) I found out the pseudoelement that I needed to make invisible:

This is what finally did the trick:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-status-display {
    display: none;
}
```